# change variable value after each match in mongodb query

Tags: mongodb, nosql

assume I have a simple collection with objects contains a field price like this:

```
{title , price}
```

I need to find items with price less than x but this is x is going to reduce after every match.
for example we have items below:

```
{
    "title":"foo",
    "price":1000
},
{
    "title":"bar",
    "price":800
},
{
    "title":"apple",
    "price":500
}
```

and the `x=2000`. in the first match we find foo and `x-1000 = 1000` so we can find bar too so `x-800 = 200` , and after that x is less than 500 and the apple would not be a match.

is it possible in mongodb to do such thing?

thanks for answering

Comment: One way that it's probably possible to do this would be worth `$setWindowFields`. What else causes a document to match and/or is there a specific order that you are processing them in?

Comment: actually Im using this in some sort of matching engine that the remaining amount of the matched should use to find the next best match (because Im trying to fill the orders at maximum fill that possible)

Comment: I guess the point of my question is that we really can't write a sample query unless we know or decide to ignore other criteria that may be relevant. For example you've implicitly shown us that data should be processed in descending price order, is that correct and required? It would make sense, I just don't want to assume one way or another as it will impact the relevance of a potential answer

Comment: aha, yes you are correct. in my case descending a field of object is what I want, but I still think the answer would be general, because other uses would be multiply or anything like that.